# XML editor for Mac or Windows

Tags: gratis, xml

I've been looking for a nice XML editor, preferably free, that works on Windows or Mac, as I have a few hundred XML files I have to make, and if there is an XML editor out there that would speed things up, rather than typing everything in X-Code, I'd be much appreciative.

- I prefer Mac, but can use Windows, if it so arises that there is a much better piece of software available.
- Auto-completion would be key.
- I more often type new XML.
- Schema checking is also important, but I have a limited ie. 2 number of schemas.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ or Sublime Edit (or any other **good** text editor) support syntax highlighting.

However that being said they aren't *great* for editing xml; probably there are plugins that improve them, but my recommendation would be [Xpontus](http://xpontus.sourceforge.net/). It matches your requirements pretty well.

- *OS:* Cross platform (specifically states that it works on [Mac, Windows and *nix](http://xpontus.sourceforge.net/installation.html) - though I only have used it on Windows)
- *Auto-completion would be key:* It supports xHTML autocomplete; don't think it knows completions for other schemas.
- *Schema checking is also important, but I have a limited ie. 2 number of schemas.* Yep that is the feature *xpontus does the best* over a good text editor.

[image]

Comment: As expected, there are XML plugins for Notepad++, they include schema-checking.

Comment: XPontus hasn't had a release since 2008, and the Mac version no longer works: it's a 32-bit program, but Mac applications are required to be 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

As per the [comment below](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/xml-editor-for-mac-or-windows/2008?noredirect=1#comment77323_2008), the last version of this program was from 2011 and it also seems to break if you have complex XML. I would suggest looking for an alternative. VSCode is now wildly popular some 5 years later, it's free and has excellent tooling and plugin support, for example - See [XML Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml).

---

On Windows, I use [firstobject XML editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm). It's fast, free, portable (a singe `.exe`) and can handle huge files. It also sports syntax highlighting.

[image]

Comment: I do not recommend this editor. I was a great fan of FOXE, but that program is from 2011 (last version 2.4.2.432) and I just discovered that it has parsing errors if the XML becomes too complex.
See the example at https://imgur.com/a/1HjtKQi where the `RoleDescriptor\KeyDescriptor\KeyInfo\X509Data\X509Certicate` XM tree completely breaks down for the second `RoleDescriptor` node

Answer (score 2):

I use [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools):

- Free
- Works with Mac/Windows/Linux
- Auto-completion
- Syntax highlighting
- [Schema checking](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xsdeditor.doc.user/topics/tvdtschm.html)
- Eclipse comes with a huge amounts of other features for XML and other languages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) for the following reasons.

- Free, Open source.
- Extendilble through [extensions and themes](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Extensions).
- Cross-platform.
- Maintained by [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/).

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Most specifically go over the requirements listed in the question and state whether it matches or not (*bonus:* list work-arounds for things it doesn't match)

Answer (score 0):

**[oXygen XML](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)** is a multi-platform XML editor if you are looking for a full-blown XML IDE. It's free and it has loads of features. Can also run as an Eclipse plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: On their website it says that you can try it for free for 30 days only, after that you’d have to purchase a license. Is there a free version hidden somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/$MYUSERID$) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.

Comment: Also - what's irritating about this, is that is basically just the eclipse XML editor.  It's certainly built on Eclipse, and doesn't appear substantially different.

Answer (score 0):

[XML Notepad 2007](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973) by Microsoft is good and free. The tree view is very nice, and being able to search by XPath selector is nice.  Its also quick and (surprisingly for Microsoft) un-bloated.

[image: XML Notepad 2007]